# Buildout error on custom mfabrik gomobiletheme

Tags: python, plone

If i create a new theme, i become a Traceback:

../bin/paster create -t gomobile_theme gomobiletheme.mytheme

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bin/paster", line 275, in <module>
    paste.script.command.run()
  File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg/paste/script/create_distro.py", line 170, in command
    egg_info_dir = pluginlib.egg_info_dir(output_dir, dist_name)
  File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg/paste/script/pluginlib.py", line 135, in egg_info_dir
    % ', '.join(all))
IOError: No egg-info directory found (looked in ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/./gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/setup.cfg/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/docs/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/README.txt/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/gomobiletheme/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/src/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/setup.py/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/CONTRIBUTORS.txt/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info, ./gomobiletheme.mytheme/CHANGES.txt/gomobiletheme.mytheme.egg-info)
```

Then I added my theme to buildout.cfg, reran it become a error like this:

```
bin/buildout
Develop: '/opt/plone4/plone4/src/gomobiletheme.mytheme'
error in gomobiletheme.mytheme setup command: Distribution
contains no modules or packages for namespace package 'gomobiletheme'
While:
 Installing.
 Processing develop directory '/opt/plone4/plone4/src/
gomobiletheme.mytheme'.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/zc/
buildout/buildout.py", line 1660, in main
   getattr(buildout, command)(args)
 File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/zc/
buildout/buildout.py", line 394, in install
   installed_develop_eggs = self._develop()
 File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/zc/
buildout/buildout.py", line 634, in _develop
   zc.buildout.easy_install.develop(setup, dest)
 File "/opt/plone4/plone4/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/zc/
buildout/easy_install.py", line 895, in develop
   *args) == 0
AssertionError
```

Know anyone whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by the template you are using. Perhaps it is outdated.

Check if your setup.py looks like this:

```
  packages=find_packages('src'),
  namespace_packages=['gomobiletheme'],
```

But you need an additional:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'},
```

directive to get the buildout working again.